# Android Build failed in travis-ci, can't get gradle from jcenter

Tags: android, travis-ci

When I build in travis-ci.
It went wrong with the log under.
This is the log.

```html
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Grain'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:1080 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

This is my .travis.yml

```
language: android

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

sudo: true

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-26.0.0
    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-26
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-android-support
```

In my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pgyer/mvn_repo_pgyer/master" }
    }
}
```

Why jcenter() redirect to `127.0.0.1:8080`, I have no idea to solve it.
Thanks.

### Solution

I have solved it,thanks.

Because I once set proxy in `gradle.properties`, and forget to delete it.After deleting, this trouble disappears.

Comment: post your full build.gradle files

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti OK, I post it now.

Comment: Check the connectivity in your CI machine. The url https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom exists. May be the machine is under a proxy.